# Can somebody prove this infinite series?

Tags: number-theory

Transformation of the Leibniz formula for $\pi$ results in the infinite series:

$$
\frac 1 {1 \times 3} + \frac 1 {5 \times 7} + \frac 1 {9 \times 11} + \frac 1 {13 \times 15} +\cdots =  \frac \pi 8
$$

If you recombine the numbers in the denominator you get e.g. the following series:

$$
\frac 1 {1 \times 5} + \frac 1 {3 \times 7} + \frac 1 {9 \times 13} + \frac 1 {11 \times 15} + \cdots
$$
which seems to approach $\dfrac{\pi / 8}{\sqrt 2}$.

Can somebody prove this?

Comment: This is not a research-level question, which this site is for. To prove the first identity you might want to consider the power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{4n+3}/(4n+1)(4n+3)$ and differentiate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same type of method as used to prove that $\pi/4 = 1 - 1/3 + 1/5 - 1/7 + \ldots$ can be used here, as soon as you write $\frac1{(2n + 1)(2n + 5)} = \frac1{4}(\frac1{2n + 1} - \frac1{2n + 5})$.

So your series is

$$\frac1{4}\left(1 + \frac1{3} - \frac1{5} - \frac1{7} + \ldots\right)$$

where the expression inside parentheses is $f(1)$ where $f(x) = x + x^3/3 - x^5/5 - x^{7}/7 + \ldots$. We calculate

$$\begin{array}{ccl}
f'(x) & = & 1 + x^2 - x^4 - x^6 + \ldots \\ 
 & = & (1 + x^2)(1 - x^4 + x^8 - x^{12} + \ldots) \\ 
 & = & \frac{1 + x^2}{1 + x^4}
\end{array}
$$

and so, since $f(0) = 0$, we have

$$f(1) = \int_0^1 \frac{1 + x^2}{1 + x^4} dx$$

Mathematica can give you the answer to this pretty quickly, but if you want to do this by hand, you can. We can factor $1 + x^4 = (1 - \sqrt{2} x + x^2)(1 + \sqrt{2} x + x^2)$; use a partial fraction decomposition to obtain

$$\frac{1 + x^2}{1 + x^4} = \frac{1/2}{1 - \sqrt{2} x + x^2} + \frac{1/2}{1 + \sqrt{2} x + x^2}$$

which after a little work integrates to

$$\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \left(\arctan(\frac{x - \sqrt{2}/2}{\sqrt{2}/2}) + \arctan(\frac{x + \sqrt{2}/2}{\sqrt{2}/2})\right)$$

and now plug in $1$ and $0$ and subtract, etc. to obtain

$$f(1) = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\left(\arctan(\sqrt{2} - 1) + \arctan(\sqrt{2} + 1)\right)$$

The expressions inside the arctangents are reciprocals of each other, so the arctangent angles are complementary: they sum to $\pi/2$. Hence $f(1) = \sqrt{2}\pi/4$, and your answer is $f(1)/4 = \sqrt{2}\pi/16$, as advertised.

Comment: Question fully answered !!! Thanks a lot for your help / explanation !!!

Comment: Okay great! If it helped you and answered it completely, please consider giving a vote up and answer acceptance. :-)